# How can I automatically upload files to remote server when I make changes

Tags: applications, file-transfer

I want to automatically upload files to a remote server when I make any changes in them using some editor. Is there some app which I can use for this purpose?

I know that this kind of thing is available in Panic Coda, but I want to continue using my favorite editor instead of switching to Coda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may depend on what type of files and what type of connection to the server you're using, but a good starting point would probably be [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/), an FTP/SFTP client. You can open files directly off the server with any program on your Mac you choose, edit them as you would a local file (I believe they're actually stored in temporary local storage), and uploaded whenever your changes are saved.

Most other FTP programs should have this functionality built in as well.